# How to point to inserted activeX combobox in worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted a combobox in sheet 7 ( named "Mainwindow").

I can't find information on how to access the combobox through VBA?

I though something like:

`Sheets("Mainwindow").combbox_Instruments.value` but it does not work.

Any ideas where one can read more about this or find a fix?

Comment: If it's an ActiveX combobox, that code should work assuming you got the name right. What happens when you use it?

Comment: Thank you all for such quick replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Sheets("Mainwindow").OLEObjects("combbox_instruments").Value`

Also, OLE objects are member of the shapes collection, so you can iterate through all the shapes in a worksheet, however the above approach should suffice.

Comment: Upvoted the correct answer. I continued with my post as the question strictly asked how to access the combobox

Answer (score 2):

An ActiveX combobox can be accessed as follows:

```
Sub Test()
Dim obj As OLEObject
Set obj = Sheets("Mainwindow").OLEObjects("combbox_instruments")
End Sub
```